# JqZoom and Twitter Bootstrap Conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jqzoom

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmurph73/REqVx/).

Using inner zoom (though it doesn't work with any of the zoom types), it should work like so: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo4

Any ideas?  Seems to be an issue with the responsive nature of Bootstrap.  Removing Bootstrap's `max-width:100%` CSS declaration on the img tag improves it a bit, but it remains broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the max-width.

```
.zoomWindow img {max-width:none}
```

Comment: Note that one might has to use just img in the rule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282949/66686

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it adding this:

```
.zoomWrapperImage img{
  max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to add some other fixes for `img max-width:100%`

This code can go immediately after instantiating the jqzoom:

```
jQuery('.zoomPup img').css('width', jQuery('.zoomPad img').width() );
jQuery('.zoomPup img').css('height', jQuery('.zoomPad img').height() );
```

And this in the general CSS:

```
.zoomPup img {max-width:none; max-height: none;}
.zoomWindow img {max-width:none; max-height: none;}
```